# Postgresql Run 'Jobs' At Specific Times

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, jobs

I have a normal problem to anyone that can't trust on applications to do their 'work/ AKA be online' and needs a DB Stored Procedure to run every minute .

Scenario :

- PostgreSQL 9.2
- Need To Run A SP To 'Compile' Information That has been inserted into the database.

1. No I Can't trust the App to be online and call this on the client side.
2. Job(s) must execute every minute.
3. Unfortunately I can't use trigger based or any 'EventBased' Model since I don't know when all the data has arrived.
4. The cluster is made of headless machines.
5. I could install  CRON on every server but that could cause unnecessary chatter
   inside the Cluster , DeadLocks , Calls at 3 AM , Pain , etc

Problem 1:
Now my problem is PGAgent requires ( As far as I know) a GUI , X and so on things I would like to avoid specially for 'just' running jobs.

Problem 2:
Also what if the server that runs the Agent ( call it Master ) dies the cluster will self heal but will the agent survive?

So how do you do it?

Comment: Cron. Just let multiple jobs run and compete for a lock. The winner performs the task.

Comment: Craig dont want to place that as an answer so i can press the magic button :)

Comment: Not without having thought it out some more. It'd help if you described your cluster. Is it a group of replicas of a single master using PostgreSQL's built-in replication? Using some other replication system? How is failover managed?

Comment: Craig , just a test env. on Xen Server and pgpoolII for Master/Slave Replication ,Query LB.

Answer (score 1):

pgAgent does *not* require a graphical user interface at all. It is a process that runs as daemon on unix.
pgAdmin is used for configuring the job details. The configuration is stored in database `postgres` where pgAgent will read it.
Once you configured your jobs, you may disconnect pgAdmin safely.

Comment: Hi eppesuig.
But i can only assume if the server dies the pgagent dies with it, no auto start on the new 'master'.
If i would install multiple copies of pgagent would end to the same thing to Cron + Locks + NOWAIT with less dependencies

Comment: So, the problem is to start pgagent whenever the database cluster become master. Probably, as you have a cluster of machines for dbms, you need a simple cluster of two machines for pgagent. That cluster would start only one instance of pgagent, and make it connect to postgresql.

Comment: That could also be a solution since we use Xen server that would handle HOST or VM Failure. But it still feels dirty that you have two more servers to manage

Comment: I don't think this would be a "dirty" solution: when you have a very important service, you need HA, so a cluster is a viable solution. Moreover, you want to keep separate all your solution components because you need to change/upgrade/fix/whatever them separately.